# Presto Sql: How to select the highest ranking value in array

Tags: sql, presto

I have an a column in table1 and each row is an array with numbers representing countries.
Table1:

```
countries    
[15, 20]     
[21, 5]      
[20, 27]     
[1, 21, 60]
```

I have a separate table (table2) with a mapping system, mapping each country number to its rank.

Table2

```
number  rank
5        1
15       2
1        3
20       4
60       5
27       6
21       7
```

I want to produce a new column in table1, which outputs the value in the array which is the highest ranked (as per the system in table2). For example, if the array is [20, 21, 5], the relative ranks as per table2 of these values are [4, 7, 1], and so the output would be 5 (because 5 is ranked #1, versus 20 which is #4 and 21 which is #7.

Example:

```
countries    answer
[15, 20]     15
[21, 5]      5
[20, 27]     20
[1, 21, 60]  1
```

I've created a map within Presto Sql using this code:

```
SELECT
    map(ARRAY_AGG(table2.number), ARRAY_AGG(table2.rank))
    FROM table2
```

I need to be able to map this to the arrays in Table1

Comment: Please elaborate your algorithm working bit more, since it is not clear enough.

Comment: Ive added a more detailed description now.

Answer (score -3):

Here you go,

```js
const ranks = {
  5: 1,
  15: 2,
  1: 3,
  20: 4,
  60: 5,
  27: 6,
  21: 7
};

const findHighestRank = (inputArray) => {
  let rankArray = [];
  let answer = 0;

  inputArray.map((arr, index) => {
    if (ranks[inputArray[index]] !== undefined) {
      return rankArray.push(ranks[inputArray[index]]);
    }
    return null;
  });

  if (rankArray.length > 0) {
    answer = Math.min(...rankArray);
  }

  return answer;
};

let foundRank = findHighestRank([15, 20]);
console.log("Answer >>>", foundRank);
```

Assuming your ranks are placed in object. Here is link to sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/highest-rank-in-array-hy62p?file=/src/index.js:0-506

Comment: Do vote if this solves your problem.

Comment: Is it possible to get this in Presto Sql?

Comment: irrelevant to db you want to use, above code works.

Comment: I need to be able to execute the code in sql